# Почему при нажатии на один элемент меняется цвет у обоих

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<div class='main'>
      <div class='m2'>Один</div>
      <div class='m2'>Два</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 let main = document.querySelector('.main')
 
document.querySelector('.main').onclick = function a(event){
    if(event.target.className='m2'){
        let b = document.querySelectorAll('.m2')
        for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            b[i].style.color='red';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы меняете цвет у обоих

```
let b = document.querySelectorAll('.m2') // находим все элементы с классом 'm2'
  for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) { // в цикле меняем их цвет
    b[i].style.color='red'; 
}
```

Comment: а что нужно сделать чтобы менялся цвет у одного?

Comment: @ЛеонидКаневский, менять только у target

Comment: @ЛеонидКаневский, `event.target.style.color='red'`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы цвет менялся только у одного, вам нужно элементам задать уникальные id и по ним менять цвет. Например, так:

HTML:

```
<div class='main'>
      <div id='id1' class='m2'>Один</div>
      <div id='id2' class='m2'>Два</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let main = document.querySelector('.main')
 
document.querySelector('.main').onclick = function a(event){
    if(event.target.className='m2'){
        let b = document.getElementById('id1');
            b.style.color='red';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

О_о там прямо так и написано: При клике, циклом пройти по всем элементам и менять их цвет)

Во-вторых, `event.target.className = 'm2'`:

`=` это оператор присваивания.
Т.е. куда бы не кликнули, className элемента станет равным "m2"

А операция присваивания возвращает то, что присвоилось.
Т.е. на проверку идет строка `if ("m2")` которая в логическом контексте всегда будет true.

`==` оператор сравнения.
Как минимум, нужно было писать `if (event.target.className == 'm2')`

Но свойство className хранит одну сплошную строку, содержащую все классы элемента. Т.е. если у элемента будет `class="m2 default"`, сравнение `"m2 default" == "m2"` вернет false. Чтобы не возиться со строкой и искать подстроки, наличие класса можно проверить по другому:

Свойство `classList` возвращает специальную коллекцию, которая хранит список всех классов элемента. У коллекции есть метод `.contains("название-класса")` - если есть такой класс, вернет true.

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main');

main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if( !e.target.classList.contains("m2") ) return;
  // Если такого класса нет у кликнутого элемента, прервать функцию через return
  
  e.target.style.color = "red";
});
```

```css
.m2 { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #123; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="m2">Один</div>
  <div class="m2">Два</div>
  <div class="m2">Три</div>
</div>
```

Можно было еще проверять так: `if ( !e.target.matches(".m2") )` — туда уже нужно передавать не просто строку-название класса, а селектор (и не только класса, но и любой другой)